# Switch pip from /usr/local/bin/pip to /usr/bin/pip

Tags: linux, pip

I m forcefully started pip from `/usr/local/bin/pip` by executing `sudo python3 -m pip install -U pip` command.

Now I want to use pip from `/usr/bin/pip`

to achieve this, I have rename the pip as `/usr/local/bin/pip_backup`

now in I ask, `which pip` or `which pip -a` it shows `/usr/bin/pip` only.

But i can not download or install any package using pip. It says:

```
[root@localhost file_name]# pip install snips-nlu

-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
some relevant

[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# which python -a /usr/bin/python 

[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# which pip -a /usr/bin/pip 
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]#

[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# ll /usr/bin/pip* 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 407 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip-2 -> ./pip-2.7 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 407 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip2 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip-2.7 -> ./pip2.7 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 407 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip2.7 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip-3 -> ./pip-3.6   
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8 May 5 2018 /usr/bin/pip-3.6 -> ./pip3.6 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16184 Oct 18 15:38 /usr/bin/pipewire

[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# ll /usr/local/bin/pip* 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr 4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip2 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr 4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 216 Apr 3 17:05 /usr/local/bin/pip3 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 216 Apr 3 17:05 /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr 4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip_bak
```

Comment: Is `pip` set as an alias? Add the output of `compgen -a` to your question.

Comment: NO, pip is not set as an alias


[root@localhost ~]# compgen -a
cp
egrep
fgrep
grep
l.
ll
ls
mv
rm
which
xzegrep
xzfgrep
xzgrep
zegrep
zfgrep
zgrep